# ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed. vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-module-federation

We are trying microfrontends with `ModuleFederationPlugin` from Webpack 5.61.0 .
I feel so helpless.
I'm using `@vue/cli@5.0.0-rc.0`.
The `vue.config.js` which exposes its modules looks like below,

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin =  require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/",
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "items",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          "./ItemsBase": "./src/components/ItemsBase.vue"
        },
        shared: require("./package.json").dependencies
      })
    ]
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
})
```

And the consumer's `vue.config.js` looks like this,

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin =  require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: "http://localhost:8081/",
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "my_shop",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {
          "items": "items@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js"
        },
        shared: require("./package.json").dependencies
      })
    ]
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
})
```

I have the `bootstrap.js` in both projects an I'm importing it like `import('./bootstrap')` from `main.js`
On the consumer project we are trying to import the **remote component** like this.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <ItemsBase></ItemsBase>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  components: {
    ItemsBase: () => import("items/ItemsBase")
  }
}
</script>
```

And this mix is based on webpack examples with vue-cli: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/vue-cli

The only difference is that they are using `vue-cli@5.0.0-beta.3` but both have same webpack version(my prototypes and webpack samples).

Now the interesting part is that I'm getting the following error in the consumer project.

```
ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed
```

any ideas?

**Edit:**
Another difference is that the vue-cli sample from webpack is using yarn and I'm using npm which is just irrelevant but thought maybe it worths mentioning because their example **works**!!!

**Edite:**
The issue is being followed on github

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it to work with `vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0`.
What i did was to delete the *splitChunks* before loading the MF like this:

`config.optimization.delete('splitChunks');`

Comment: huh, thanks. I will try this out. The config is this new instance which is required in vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0 right?

Comment: Ok, as I checked, it worked. I added the splitChunks under `configureWebpack -> optimization -> splitChunks: false`

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out why this is happening.
I opened an issue in github on vue-cli.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6823

On Saturday(06.11) the vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0 release on npm and well with npm I could not again create a new vue app for any of the vue-cli versions. because it adds the version 5.0.0 of each packages in package.json and apparently they don't exist in npm but it works with yarn.
I could not get the module federation to work with `vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0` but as used in the webpack example for vue-cli I could get it to work with `vue-cli@5.0.0-beta-3`.